# how to generate random numbers with sequence in R

Tags: r

I need to generate random numbers between 20 and 50 with 5 increments. For example, the numbers must be 20, 25, 30, 25, 50, 45 etc. The difference between numbers should be 5.

I tried this:

```
x<-floor(runif(50,20,50))
```

this gives me any number between 20 and 50. Is there an easy way to do this in R?

Comment: check `?sample` and `?seq`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think Arun was referring to this:

```
set.seed(123)
sample(seq(from = 20, to = 50, by = 5), size = 50, replace = TRUE)
#  [1] 30 45 30 50 50 20 35 50 35 35 50 35 40 40 20 50 25 20 30 50 50 40 40 50 40
# [26] 40 35 40 30 25 50 50 40 45 20 35 45 25 30 25 20 30 30 30 25 20 25 35 25 50
```

Comment: Or `sample(seq(20, 50, by=5))`.

Comment: @SimonO101, that is only giving me 5 data points and not in increments of 5. I need 50 points between 20 and 50 with 5 increments.

Comment: @user1471980, Read `?sample`. `sample(seq(20, 50, by=5), 50, replace=TRUE)`

Answer (score 1):

Very similar to your original code, but dividing and multiplying by 5 to get the rounding in 5's not 1's.

```
floor(runif(50,20,50)/5)*5
 [1] 45 30 45 35 45 35 25 30 35 40 20 45 25 30 25 40 30 40 40 40 20 30 30 40 35 30 25 45 25 20 45 20 35 35 30 20 20 20 20 35 35 45 45 45 45 20
[47] 45 40 40 20
```